# How to improve my question on "Helpful Travel Websites"?

Tags: discussion

Would someone please advise and enlighten on improving https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/helpful-travel-websites ? In my last sentence, I tried to exemplify some specifics and explain the desires of my search, but my question was still closed?

By virtue of moderator mindcorrosive's answer, I'm glad that I asked my original question and this Meta question, because mindcorrosive's answer enlightened me about Wikivoyage, of which I had never been aware until this answer and which Google failed to illumine!

Thanks to this enlightenment, I`m still interested in learning about answers here, so what are some suggestions or advice on improving the question? I specify "pictures" in my question because I want to eliminate travel websites without sufficiently many of them, such as those cited in your answer: "news sources, Wikipedia, ..."

Answer (score 4):

Even after your edit, the question is too broad. Have you by any chance seen [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the Help center?

Your post (it's not even a question really) isn't what we do here on Travel-SE. I understand you have a genuine interest in receiving that sort of information, and it can potentially be a useful resource, but this is not what Stack Exchange sites do.

Your post, as it stands -- and this is a symptom of a not-that-good question by itself -- is just asking for a long list of recommendations, is way too general, open-ended, and is thoroughly subjective ("helpful" for whom? Seasoned travellers? Families with children? Lone trekkers?). Virtually any website on the internet that deals even tangentially with travelling is going to be "helpful" -- news sources, travel blogs, Wikipedia, Wikivoyage, travel forums, frequent flyer discussion boards, WWOOF, AirBnB, accommodation services, caravan enthusiast websites, social websites, etc. Do you really think listing potentially thousands of websites would be helpful to anybody? Search engines already do this, and way better than anyone else can hope to.

These types of questions and attempts to accumulate useful resources just isn't what Travel-SE tries to do -- because there are better ways of obtaining the same information and much more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I`m still interested in learning about answers here, so what are some suggestions or advice on improving the question? I specify "pictures" in my question because I want to eliminate travel websites without sufficiently many of them, such as those cited in your answer: "news sources,  Wikipedia, ..."

Comment: What does WWOOF mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWOOF